# Why won't JMockit use this (apparently) valid Injectable?

Tags: java, junit4, jmockit

I recently refactored one of my classes to accept an iterable of generic objects in its constructor and am now unable to get JMockit to instantiate the `@Tested` field of the test class.  Here's a stripped-down test case which exhibits the same problem:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import mockit.Injectable;
import mockit.Tested;
import org.junit.Test;

public class FooTest {
    public static interface Generic<T> {}

    public static class Foo<T> implements Generic<T> {
        public Foo(Iterable<Generic<T>> iterable) {}
    }

    @Tested Foo<Object> tested;
    @Injectable Iterable<Generic<Object>> injectable = Collections.emptyList();

    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
        // java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No constructor in class FooTest$Foo that can be satisfied by available injectables
    }
}
```

I realize I could trivially work around this by created `tested` in a `@Before` method, but I want to understand why this is failing, first.  :-)

I'm using Java 1.7.0_51, JMockit 1.8, and JUnit 4.11.

Comment: I don't know JMockit, but doesn't `Foo` need to be declared `static`? Otherwise there's an implicit `FooTest.this` instance that needs to be provided.

Comment: @DanielPryden Whoops, that was a mistake simplifying the test case.  The (mis?)behavior is identical if the interface and class are static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Tested` feature doesn't fully support generic type parameters yet, as of JMockit 1.8.

That said, JMockit 1.9 (to be released shortly, Jun 22) adds support for scenarios like this one.